# How to preserve spacing when storing a string into an array? JavaScript React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with a `<textarea>`. On submit that string gets stored into an array. Sometimes the strings have blank lines or additional spacing and I want to preserve this spacing. Right now, the only spacing preserved is the spacing between words. The `handleSubmit` component consist of a `useRef` hook that is pushed into the array. I'm looking for another approach for storing the string that would preserve spacing. I appreciate all ideas! Thank you for your time!

```
 const textAreaRef = useRef();   
 const [entryArray, setEntry] = useState([]);

 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        const updatedList = [...entryArray];
        updatedList.push(textAreaRef.current.value);
        textAreaRef.current.value = ""; // Clears value
        setEntry(updatedList);
}

return (
        <div>
        <form class="entryForm"  onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <label for="newEntryId"> 
            <span>New Entry:</span>
            <textarea  type="text" id="newEntryId" name="newEntryName" rows="30" cols="75" 
              defaultValue="What's on your mind?" ref = {textAreaRef} 
                /> 
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       
        </form>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: I suspect this is a fault in debugging assumptions.  Are you sure *this code* is stripping out whitespace?  Or are you using *some other code* to *observe* the result and not seeing the whitespace?  How are you observing it?  Are you familiar with how browsers render whitespace?  As a guess I suspect what you're actually looking for is a rich text editor plugin of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't replicate the issue, works fine.

Vanilla js example, but works the same in React

```js
const area = document.querySelector('textarea')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const saved = []

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  saved.push(area.value)
  area.value = ''
  console.log(saved)
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button>save</button>
```